# Why is listShuttle component in richFaces not getting updated?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I am a newbie for Richfaces components. When I am using the `<rich:listShuttle>`, the Arraylist specified in the targetValue is now getting updated with the latest data?

**MyJSF File**

```
<a4j:region>
<rich:listShuttle sourceValue="#{bean.selectItems}" id="one"
 targetValue="#{bean.selectItemsone}" var="items" listsHeight="150"
 sourceListWidth="130" targetListWidth="130"
 sourceCaptionLabel="Intial Items"
 targetCaptionLabel="Selected Items" converter="Listconverter">
    <rich:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{items.value}"></h:outputText>
    </rich:column>
</rich:listShuttle>
</a4j:region>
<a4j:region>
<a4j:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.action}" />
</a4j:region>
```

**My Managed Bean**

```
private List<String> selectedData;
private List<BeanItems> selectItems;
private List<BeanItems> selectItemsone;

public String action() {
    System.out.println(selectItems);
    System.out.println(selectItemsone);
    System.out.println("Select Item List");
    Iterator<BeanItems> iterator = selectItems.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        BeanItems item = (BeanItems) iterator.next();
        System.out.println(item.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("/nSelect Item one list ");
    Iterator<BeanItems> iterator2 = selectItemsone.iterator();
    while (iterator2.hasNext()) {
        BeanItems item = (BeanItems) iterator2.next();
        System.out.println(item.getValue());
    }
    return "";
}

public void setSelectedData(List<String> selectedData) {
    this.selectedData = selectedData;
}

public List<String> getSelectedData() {
    return selectedData;
}

/**
 * @return the selectItems
 */
public List<BeanItems> getSelectItems() {
    if (selectItems == null) {
        selectItems = new ArrayList<BeanItems>();
        selectItems.add(new BeanItems("value4", "label4"));
        selectItems.add(new BeanItems("value5", "label5"));
        selectItems.add(new BeanItems("value6", "label6"));
        selectItems.add(new BeanItems("value7", "label7"));
        selectItems.add(new BeanItems("value8", "label8"));
        selectItems.add(new BeanItems("value9", "label9"));
        selectItems.add(new BeanItems("value10", "label10"));

    }
    return selectItems;
}

/**
 * @return the selectItemsone
 */
public List<BeanItems> getSelectItemsone() {
    if (selectItemsone == null) {
        selectItemsone = new ArrayList<BeanItems>();
        selectItemsone.add(new BeanItems("value1", "label1"));
        selectItemsone.add(new BeanItems("value2", "label2"));
        selectItemsone.add(new BeanItems("value3", "label3"));
    }
    return selectItemsone;
}
```

**My Converter Class**

```
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,String value) {  
             int index = value.indexOf(':');  
             return new BeanItems(value.substring(0, index), value.substring(index + 1));  
         }  

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,Object value) {  
             BeanItems beanItems = (BeanItems) value; 
             return beanItems.getValue() + ":" + beanItems.getData();  
        }
```

**My BeanItems Class**

```
private String data;  //Getter & setter
private String value; //Getter & setter

public BeanItems() {

}

public BeanItems(String value, String data) {
    this.value = value;
    this.data = data;
}
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((data == null) ? 0 : data.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((value == null) ? 0 : value.hashCode());
    return result;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    final BeanItems other = (BeanItems) obj;
    if (data == null) {
        if (other.data != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!data.equals(other.data))
        return false;
    if (value == null) {
        if (other.value != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!value.equals(other.value))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I don't have extensive practical experience with RichFaces, so I may be wrong, but shouldn't it all be inside the **same** `a4j:region`?

Comment: when i but all the components inside the same region, the action method specified for the command button is not called, like the button is itself inactive.

Comment: thanks daedlus and BalusC for ur answers and tips, the problem is resolved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your question is that the target list is not getitng populated then i think you are supposed to override equals , hash code method for the wrapper object[BeanItem] since in the converter you are constructing new object every time in getAsObject method.

Also try putting a h:message tag wrapped in --a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true"-- in your page to print any conversion errors that might be getting generated.

Comment: @daedlus : i have overrided hash code and the equals method already, i have added my BeanItem class in the question.

Comment: if i did some wrong stuff while overriding the method, please mention it and thanks for the advice

Comment: @daedlus: Thanks for the answer its working now. even if the comman button is inside or outside the region

Comment: @Hari: Could you please elaborate more on how you managed to fix the issue? What was wrong in your code?

Comment: @Iravanchi : There was some validation errors while performing the operation, i had used the outputmessage component to find the error and rectified it accordingly.